# ASWebAuthenticationSessionError.canceledLogin does not fire when swiping down to dismiss

Tags: ios, aswebauthenticationsession

I am creating an `ASWebAuthenticationSession` session and in the completion handler I have cleanup tasks for when the user cancel's the login:

```
let session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: redirectURI) { (callbackURL: URL?, error: Error?) in
    if case .ASWebAuthenticationSessionError.canceledLogin? = error {
        // clean up tasks
    }

    // proceed...
}
```

In iOS 13+, the user is able to swipe down to dismiss, but the entire completion handler is not fired at all in this scenario. I do not want to disable this gesture by enabling isModalInPresentation.

Is there a way to make the ASWebAuthenticationSessionError.canceledLogin fire for this case, or how can I detect the user swiping down to cancel the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` session?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who may stumble across this question I ended up being able to capture the error by doing this in the completion handler...

```
    if let error, !isCancelledLoginError(error) {
        /// Capture a normal error in here
    }
```

And outside of the completion handler the function that checks if the user clicked `Cancel`...

```
    private func isCancelledLoginError(_ error: Error) -> Bool {
        (error as NSError).code == ASWebAuthenticationSessionError.canceledLogin.rawValue
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found out, that the ViewController from which the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` is presented from, gets a call of its `dismiss()` function if the user swiped down the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` screen. So if you want to react on this user interaction, this is the only place where this can be done as far as I know.
Find out, from which ViewController the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` is presented from and the override its `dismiss()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Frustrating how difficult this is, but I was able to detect the dismissal by overriding the window's `willRemoveSubview()`.

```
class MyWindow: UIWindow {
    var willRemoveSubviewCallback: (() -> ())?

    override func willRemoveSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        super.willRemoveSubview(subview)
        willRemoveSubviewCallback?()
    }
}

func signIn() {
    let url = ...
    let scheme = ...
    let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window as! MyWindow
    
    var hasCalledHandler = false
    let handler: ASWebAuthenticationSession.CompletionHandler = { [weak window] (callbackUrl, error) in
        guard !hasCalledHandler else {
            return
        }
        hasCalledHandler = true
        window?.willRemoveSubviewCallback = nil
        
        // Handle callbackurl / error...
    }
    
    let session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: scheme, completionHandler: handler)
    session.presentationContextProvider = window
    let success = session.start()
    if success {
        window.willRemoveSubviewCallback = {
            handler(nil, NSError(domain: ASWebAuthenticationSessionError.errorDomain, code: ASWebAuthenticationSessionError.canceledLogin.rawValue, userInfo: nil))
        }
    }
}

extension UIWindow: ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {
    public func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this if the context provider is a UIView instead?